# Approximate an integral

Tags: integration, physics, approximation

In a physics textbook, I came across the integral
$$I(r_1,r_0)=\int_{r_0}^{r_1}\frac{1}{1-2m/r}\left[1-\frac{r_0^2(1-2m/r)}{r^2(1-2m/r_0)}\right]^{-1/2}dr$$
The author said that the integrand can be expanded to first order in $m/r$ (since here $r_1>r_0\gg m$) to obtain
$$I(r_1,r_0)\simeq\int_{r_0}^{r_1}\frac{r}{r^2-r_0^2}\left[1+\frac{2m}{r}+\frac{mr_0}{r(r+r_0)}\right]dr.$$
How to do that? I have really no idea how he came up with that second integral.

Comment: Note: in your first definite integral you can't use $r$ to denote both the limit of integration and the dummy variable of integration.

Comment: @DavidH Physicists always do that, but I know its confusing... Let me change it.

Comment: You're not really approximating an integral, but an integrand.

Comment: @Spenser I hear ya. I'm a physicist too, but I was raised by very anal mathematicians =p

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Can you give the title of the textbook ?